# Minecraft Incompatible Heap Sizes?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I changed my Java XMX to have 2GB of RAM because I hate the lag I'm getting, but I get a strange error message:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Incompatible minimum and maximum heap sizes specified
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
```

My commandline:

```
-Xmx2G -Xms2G
```

Whatever this `_JAVA_OPTIONS` is, it's overriding my XMX setting. I've looked through all of my Windows configs, but I have been unable to find it. Why is it happening, and how do I fix it?

---

I have no environment variable named `_JAVA_OPTIONS` in my system that I can see.

---

Upon further testing, this only happens with the Minecraft exe file. When lanuching the Launcher JAR, it works perfectly.

Comment: `-Xmx` specifies the maximum heap size. `-Xms` specifies the initial heap size - that means the memory that will be allocated even if it is not needed right now. Try decreasing `-Xms`.

Comment: @MinecraftShamrock The problem is that something is overriding the Java Options I'm setting. I want to remove this override.

Comment: Are you launching it using a script or using the "additional java options" in the launcher?

Comment: @JeffreyLin Additional Java Options

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27414699/picked-up-java-options-when-no-such-environment-variable-exists), it's due to Razer. If you have Razer programs open, shut them all down & try again.